# nestjs graphql infinite loop of parent case 'incompatible' error when using prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I am using `prisma` with `nestjs`. Created a entity like this

```js
import { ObjectType, Field, Int } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Category {
  @Field(() => Int, { description: '' })
  id: number;
  @Field(() => String)
  title: string;
  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  parentId: number;
  @Field(() => Category, { nullable: true })
  parent: Category;
  @Field(() => Boolean)
  isSysCatDir: boolean;
}
```

and use prisma like this

```js
  async findAll(
    page: number = 1,
    perPage: number = 10,
  ): Promise<PaginatedCategory> {
    const xprisma = this.prisma.$extends(extension);
    const paginatedUsers = await xprisma.category.paginate({
      limit: perPage,
      page: page,
      orderBy: { id: 'desc' },
      include: { parent: true },
    });
    return {
      result: paginatedUsers.result,
      page: paginatedUsers.page,
      total: paginatedUsers.count,
      prePage: paginatedUsers.limit,
    };
  }
```

Then get an error like this: `The types of 'category.parent' are incompatible`